# Trying to access gitlab repo returns: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have GitLab 7.0.0 installed - and all has been working well - until I wanted to make my server a bit more save (experienced some brute-force attacks).. so I changed in /etc/ssh/sshd_config some things:

```
AllowUsers git #and some other users   

PasswordAuthentication no
```

SSH connection through PUTTY and SSH keys can be established..

So can I use GitLab this way? Did I miss some config?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try, as suggested in [issue 5501](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5501) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sag47/7255904)

```
Match User git
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

And leave out the AllowUsers part (to see if it is working, since [issue 5306](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5306) reports some trouble with that option)

Check also the shell associated with that account ([issue 6266](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6266#issuecomment-34509438))
You have other suggestions in [issue 4730](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4730#issuecomment-23266035).

Comment: Nope.. didn't help and I want all the users to only accept public keys - and I don't want anyone to be able to log into the root account directly

Comment: @fodinabor Ok. Did you open an issue on GitLab side?

Comment: well It seems like that not only GitLab has a problem :( my Easy-WI also isn't able to connect to the server.. using public keys ..